# iOS 9 alarm icon in status bar behaviour change?

Tags: alarm, ios

I just updated to iOS 9.0.2 direct from iOS 8.4 and this morning (a Sunday) I noticed the alarm icon in my status bar.

I have two repeating weekday alarms, and I *thought* the previous behaviour was to show the icon if you had a pending alarm *on the same day*, but now it seems to be present if there are any upcoming alarms active, even if they're days away.

Similarly I *thought* that if I dismissed a repeating alarm and there were no other alarms active that day, the icon would disappear for the rest of that day. This doesn't happen now.

I see a possibly related unanswered post on Apple Support Communities: [Why is the alarm icon showing with no alarm set?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7220510)

The [iPhone User Guide for iOS 8.4](https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1565/en_US/iphone_user_guide.pdf) on page 15 says the icon means "an alarm is set", which could mean either really.

Is this new behaviour, or am I misremembering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not new behaviour. The alarm icon shows in the status bar if you have an alarm scheduled at any time, regardless if it is on the same day or not.

Comment: I just realized my iPad is still on iOS 8 and tried it and, sure enough, the icon stays. So it seems I am just losing my marbles. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: No problem @CupawnTae

Comment: Agreed, It is showing up if any alarm is active in the future. Just set up one for the next day and the icon will assure you about it.. It´ like that on iOS 6. So it´s not new in iOS 9